# How to write a query where count(columnValue) = 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write a query where count(columnValue) = 1 and there are no repeat of the same value in any of the rows in the table

```
SELECT 
    iDataItemID 
FROM 
    MSAOnline4..OT_BackendUpdate_DataItemStatus 
WHERE
    COUNT(DI.iDataItemID) = 1
```

I want to print only iDataItem = 2 from the below result,

```
iDataItemID Status
1   1
1   2
2   1
```

Comment: ...GROUP BY iDataItemID... (Group By is convenient for Aggregate functions such as count) and ...HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 ...(the Having clause can be used to impose conditions on Aggregate function results)

Answer (score 1):

you can use below query :

```
select iDataItemID
FROM MSAOnline4..OT_BackendUpdate_DataItemStatus  
GROUP BY iDataItemID 
HAVING count(iDataItemID)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

you do it by Group by and having:

```
SELECT iDataItemID
FROM MSAOnline4..OT_BackendUpdate_DataItemStatus 
GROUP BY iDataItemID  
HAVING Count(DISTINCT iDataItemID) = 1
```